# How to set a good distance in zoom of two locations on google maps android

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I need to create something to determine a good zoom level based on two locations, from A to B.

**This is basic where I draw on the map after consume a Locations Api from google**

```
private void drawnNewRoute(){
    if(polyline == null){
        po = new PolylineOptions();

        for(int i = 0, tam = latLngs.size(); i < tam; i++){
            po.add(latLngs.get(i));
        }

        po.color(Color.BLACK).width(10);
        polyline = mMap.addPolyline(po);
        LatLng myCurrentLocation = new LatLng(lat, lon);

        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myCurrentLocation, 13));

        mMarkerNewPosition = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(finalLocaltion).title(finalLocationName));
        mMarkerNewPosition.showInfoWindow();

    }
    else{
        polyline.setPoints(latLngs);
    }
}
```

I have a list of all locations with a `LatLngs` class, I was thinking of take that list and dived for two take a first location from the rest and do some math to get a "good" zoom level, but I don't know how to measure this. Maybe a math based on the distance, I have the distance too! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using `LatLngBounds`.

```
LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
// Add your locations to bounds using builder.include, maybe in a loop
LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
//Then construct a cameraUpdate
CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 0);
//Then move the camera
map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
```

Comment: the second parameter of `newLatLngBounds` what I put, zero?

Comment: That is `padding`. It specifies the amount of distance to be padded from the screen so that your location points will not end up exactly at the edge of the screen. You can try using a positive value that makes your locations look appropriate on the screen. Its value should not have a very big impact on the functionality, though.